# What are the hotkeys to navigate the timeline?

Tags: shortcut, keyframes

I am looking for a way to move the timeline a specific amount, scroll, etc. even if the *Timeline* window is not open. Is this possible?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

<kbd>→</kbd> 1 frame forward
<kbd>←</kbd> 1 frame backward

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> end frame
<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> start frame

<kbd>↑</kbd> next keyframe 
<kbd>↓</kbd> previous keyframe

<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> next marker
<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>  previous marker

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> 10 frames forward
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> 10 frames back

Comment: Alt+A play/pause animation.

Comment: play/pause I use space key.

Answer (score 26):

Hold down the <kbd>Alt</kbd> button and start scrolling the **Mouse Wheel**.

***Scrolling down will let you go forward*** in a *Timeline*, scrolling up works vice versa.
You can do it in almost every window type you want and it works even if the *Timeline* window is not open.

Note: this shortcut works well in the *Video Sequence*, *NLA*, *Dope Sheet* and *Graph* editors also.
[image: Example Gif]

Answer (score 8):

(I know this is an old question, but I got here while looking for an answer. So, just for the record...)

You can change the size of "steps" (or "jumps") Blender does (when pressing Left/Right, Shift + Up/Down, and even Alt + Wheel/Scroll) by changing the "Delta" parameter in the shortcuts "Frame Offset".

Path: Blender User Preferences > Input > search for a shortcut named "Frame Offset".
Then change the "Delta" value to whatever you want (default is 10).

[image: Blender User Preferences > Input > Shortcut "Frame Offset"]

Comment: And remember to set Shift Down Arrow Delta value to negative!

Answer (score 2):

Being inspired by [Paul Gonet's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/34701/2952) and [Ricardo Roehe's answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/63362/2952) I realized that if you like the mouse scroll method you can use the mouse for the other frame navigation methods too!

Here are some examples... (customize to your liking)

<sup>Location: **Preferences → Keymap → Frames**</sup>

### Jump 10 frames forward / backward

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>Wheel Down **/** <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>Wheel Up

[image]

### Jump to next / previous keyframe

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>Wheel Down **/** <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>Wheel Up

[image]

### Jump to end / start of playback range

<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>Wheel Down **/** <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd>Wheel Up

[image]

<sub>Note: I could not find commands in the Keymap Preferences for Next / Previous Marker. I'm not sure if they still exist in 2.8+</sub>

Hopefully some will find this useful, as you can leave your hand on the modifier keys instead of having to move it over to the arrow keys each time you want to move along the timeline. A configuration like this seems to allow the shortest keyboard travel time.

<sub>Note: When configuring shortcuts, checkboxes for "Next Keyframe" or "Last Frame" etc. are greyed out by default. You must click to interact with them to make them active, otherwise these shortcuts won't register. In other words, greyed out does *not* mean FALSE.</sub>