# How can I jump to the first frame in the timeline?

Tags: animation, shortcut, timeline

As I was making an Animation I found my self to oftenly press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to start and stop the green slider, and then when I stopped it I had to get it with my mouse and move it back to the beginning of the Timeline to see the Animation again.

[image]

I know that you can cancel the animation, and take the slider to the beginning when its playing by pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd> key but I can't get used to that.

You can see what I mean in the video below on Minute **5:40** **-** **5:44**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NsdRUk807qk

Comment: Please see this question also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20952/are-there-hotkeys-to-navigate-the-timeline

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Left Arrow</kbd>, in the timeline, moves you to the first frame; <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right Arrow</kbd> gets you to the last frame.