# How can I add more animation to my existing animation?

Tags: animation

When I make change to an existing animation, such as colour of object, and press animation again, it won't animate. What am I missing?

I'm just learning blender 2.76.

Comment: Did you try to restart animation by going to the first frame (`Shift`+`Left Arrow` shortcut) ? See more info about animation shortcuts [in related question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/20953/1245)

Comment: What are you trying to watch that does not change accordingly to what you've altered? because if you have already rendered the animation you will have to re-render it in order to see any changes made... when you say "press animation" what exactly do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the changes you make to an object to be saved, you need to insert a keyframe on the property or whatever it is that you changed. To do this, in this case, mouse over the color field and press <kbd>I</kbd>.

Alternatively, you can open the graph editor, by selecting it from the dropdown that appears when you press thebutton on the bottom left corner of thewindow (in the default screen layout), and then edit the f-curves for the property you wish to change manually.