# What is the number in corner of the 3D view?

Tags: interface, 3d-view

At the bottom-left corner of the 3D view there is some white text with the name of the selected object, preceded by a number in parentheses.  What does this number mean?

[image]

Comment: It shows what frame on a timeline you already are.

Comment: I thought it was the up count on the first comment on the BSE question within the first 8 minutes

Comment: By the way [explanation in the wiki](https://www.blender.org/manual/fr/editors/3dview/navigate/introduction.html) of it probably should be modified.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It shows what frame on a timeline you already are. It is very useful if you e.g. maximized the window with **View -> Toggle Maximize Area** (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>) and don't see your *time cursor* (the green vertical line) on the *Timeline*. Please see how to navigate it btw ([What are the hotkeys to navigate the timeline?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20952/are-there-hotkeys-to-navigate-the-timeline)).

[image]

It's also very helpful as it shows what frame on a timeline the animation keyframe is inserted (the number changes the color from white to orange then).

[image]