# How to go back to previous state from amimation player?

Tags: interface

I m new to blender. We play animation by pressing Alt+A. Now how to go back to previous state. Stopping anim player just pauses the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After pressing Alt+A the animation is played back.

During the playback:

1. Press <kbd>Escape</kbd> to stop the playback and return to the original frame before playback.
2. Press <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> to stop playback resting on the current frame.

---

If you haven't changed the user preferences, this is the shortcut setting (note the checked property **Restore Frame**).

[image]

Comment: In addition you can check this answer for some useful tips: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20952/what-are-the-hotkeys-to-navigate-the-timeline

Comment: Hey..thanks for the response. Alt+A does stop the animation. But the backspace seems to do nothing. Is there any value to input key for backspace that i need to assign in user preferences. If yes plz guide how. Backspace is not doing anything. I am using the latest version of blender 2.78 .

Comment: @RahulJha Not *backspace*, the **escape** key is located on the top right of most keyboards.

Comment: @RahulJha Sorry, top ***left***.