# How to start playing the video from the green cursor rather than from the beginning of the time-line?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

In Video Editor mode hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> starts playback from the beginning of the timeline.
How to start playing the video from the green cursor?

(I found this question asked on reddit by nightmareFluffy, but it is too late to answer it there.
It's one of the most basic things for video editing and I could not find an answer to it anywhere so I'm posting this question here for others to find.)
My version is 2.79

Comment: With the current default installation from 2.80 on (left-click-select), the Playback shortcut is Spacebar. Alt+A is reserved for Deselecting.

Comment: I have 2.79 should've specified that - `spacebar` opens some dialogue to pick an action. Thanks for the tip, I'll upgrade I guess : )

Answer (score 4):

From the `Timeline` editor's bottom menu select `Playback` and tick `Follow`.
Then <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> will play from the cursor.

Comment: Related: [What are the hotkeys to navigate the timeline?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/20952/what-are-the-hotkeys-to-navigate-the-timeline)

Comment: This answer is outdated and no longer valid: There is no tickmark in the Playback menu called Follow, but only "Follow Current Frame" and alt - a does no longer play video (I think they changed it in one 3.x release)

Answer (score 1):

Even with those controls, I couldn't get Blender to play from the beginning of my clip. Why? The video timestamp that I was trying to play from was outside the "frame range" in the sequencer. As a result, it bumped the playback start time to the beginning of the current frame range, which was the beginning of the video.

To fix: In the sequencer, clicking View -> Range -> Set Frame Range to Strips extended the frame range to the full strip. Once I did this, I was able to play from any point in the strip.